# Does page view controller supports iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using page view controller based app for iPad. It is working on simulator, but not on device that have ios 4.3. Does it means ios 4.3 does not supports it or anything else. I have gone through apple reference also, but not found any solution. Can any one guide for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, UIPageViewController is available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: sorry for asking, but are you sure, can you give some reference of it.

Comment: Yes, check this apple reference here. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: so wait, wouldn't your answer be "no" then?

Comment: @turbo, as per the documentation, it will work only in iOS version > 5

Comment: Yes, but the question seems to be "is UIPageViewController supported in iOS 4.3" to which the answer would be: no.

Comment: Oh! Inside the question description he asked "Does it means ios 4.3 does not supports it or anything else", so i said YES. I think author of the question understand my answer. :-)